# JAXB different elements in list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have some XML-files that have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ROOT xmlns="http://www.XXX.com/YYY"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DOCUMENT>
        <title>Doc 1</title>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <title>Doc 2</title>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <TEXT>
        <content>Text 1</content>
    </TEXT>
    <TEXT>
        <content>Text 2</content>
    </TEXT>
    <ITEM>
        <id>1</id>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <id>2</id>
    </ITEM>
</ROOT>
```

I want to parse the files using JAXB and thus I have to create models for all the elements. But what would the model for the `ROOT` element be? Is it allowed in XML to put different datatypes in one list?

I called my model `DocumentList` but what is the generic type of my list? Can I do it with one list or do I have have to create different lists?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
public class DocumentList {

    private List elements;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

My model classes look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "DOCUMENT")
    private List<Document> documents;

    @XmlElement(name = "TEXT")
    private List<Text> texts;

    @XmlElement(name = "ITEM")
    private List<Item> items;

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "DOCUMENT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document {

    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    private String title;

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "TEXT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Text {

    @XmlElement(name = "content")
    private String content;

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ITEM")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id;

}
```

Getters and setters are implemented, too.

Now I get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.XXX.com/YYY", local:"ROOT"). Expected elements are <{}DOCUMENT>,<{}TEXT>,<{}ITEM>,<{}ROOT>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.siemens.xmlmerger.Test.main(Test.java:53)
```

Why does it expect `<{}ROOT>`? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: this looks like a root class which contains a list of documents and a list of text and a list of items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use three different lists (one for each type).

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
public class DocumentList {

    @XmlElement(name="DOCUMENT")
    private List documents;

    @XmlElement(name="TEXT")
    private List texts;

    @XmlElement(name="ITEMS")
    private List items;

}
```

Comment: I get an error with this approach now. I posted the output in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

There are  couple of different ways to support this use case if you want to represent it as a single list (see below).  You could also represent it as separate lists.

### OPTION #1 - Each Element Corresponds to a Unique Class

If each element name in your list corresponds to a different class, then you can use one `List` by leveraging `@XmlElements` and doing the following:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DocumentList {

    @XmlElements({
       @XmlElement(name="DOCUMENT", type=Document.class),
       @XmlElement(name="TEXT", type=Text.class),
       @XmlElement(name="ITEM", type=Item.class)
    })
    private List elements;

}
```

### OPTION #2- Multiple Elements Correspond to the Same Class

If the `Class` of the entry in the `List` is not enough to uniquely map it to an element, then you are going to need to leverage `JAXBElement` to maintain the element information.  Note how we have we have removed the `@XmlElements` annotation and replaced it with `@XmlElementRefs`.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DocumentList {

    @XmlElementRefs({
       @XmlElementRef(name="DOCUMENT", type=JAXBElement.class),
       @XmlElementRef(name="TEXT", type=JAXBElement.class),
       @XmlElementRef(name="ITEM", type=JAXBElement.class)
    })
    private List elements;

}
```

Along with the `@XmlElementRefs`/`@XmlElementRef` annotations we need to provide `@XmlElementDecl` annotations on a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="DOCUMENT")
    public JAXBElement<String> createDocument(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("DOCUMENT"), String.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="TEXT")
    public JAXBElement<String> createText(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("TEXT"), String.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="ITEM")
    public JAXBElement<String> createItem(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("ITEM"), String.class, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is using separate lists like the others suggested no option?

Comment: @feuerball - You can have them as separate lists as well.

Comment: I chose the "separate list" option, but I get an error now. I have updated my original post with a new XML-excerpt, my code and the eroor message.

Comment: @feuerball - This article will help you map the namespace qualification:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Setting the package level namespace did the trick. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the xml will be mapped into attributes of the binding class

so

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
public class DocumentList {

    @XmlElement(name="DOCUMENT")
    private List documents;

    @XmlElement(name="TEXT")
    private List texts;

    @XmlElement(name="ITEMS")
    private List items;
```

In above class attributes are mapped with list of elements in xml.

I hope you understand